# Gulp и кодировка 1251

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, перекодировка, gulp

Проект собираю gulp'ом. Изначально все делал в utf-8, а на сервере 1251. Заменил в html meta utf-8 на windows-1251. В sublime делаю save with encoding windows-1251. И собранный gulp'ом html файл заменяет кириллицу на "����� ��������" А в начальном файле все нормально. Приходится все отменять.
И теперь для корректного отображения на сервере я проделываю шаги:
1. Сохраняю файл в utf-8
2. Скидываю его на фтп
3. Открываю на фтп этот файл и пересохраняю в 1251. 
Чистое шаманство. Как упростить этот процесс?

Answer (score 2):

Не надо использовать windows-1251. Даже РПЦ не признаёт [эту неправославную кодировку](http://absurdopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Windows-1251).

Comment: @DmitryN позвольте поинтересоваться, почему?

Comment: если РПЦ не признает, значит я на правильном пути. Я не могу менять кодировку, к сожалению.

Comment: поменяйте сервер